# Is there any way listener a interpolation changes from a directive?

Tags: angular

I have a directive for rendering markdown. The first time works fine but if the content changes because it is async, the directive is not reloaded. Is there any way to listen that change?

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMarkdown]'
})
export class MarkdownDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  private instance;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.instance = new Viewer({
      el: this.el.nativeElement,
      initialValue: this.el.nativeElement.textContent
    });
  }
}
```

Component which uses the directive:

```ts
<app-detail [entity$]="item$">
  <ng-template #entity let-entity="item">
    {{ entity.description }} // This reload properly when the observable get a new value
    <p appMarkdown>{{ entity.description }}</p> // This stucks in the first value and not changes
  </ng-template>
</app-detail>
```

The only way I found to do it is with using @Input() but it looks like a workaround to pass twice the value as input and as content.

```ts
export class MarkdownDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() set content(value) {
    if (this.instance) { this.instance.setMarkdown(value); }
  }

  private instance;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.instance = new Viewer({
      el: this.el.nativeElement,
      initialValue: this.el.nativeElement.textContent
    });
  }
}
```

```
<app-detail [entity$]="item$">
  <ng-template #entity let-entity="item">
    {{ entity.description }}
    <p appMarkdown [content]="entity.description">{{ entity.description }}</p>
  </ng-template>
</app-detail>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to abstract out the `async` pipe in an outer container using `*ngIf` directive. Try the following

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(item$ | async) as item">
  <p appMarkdown>{{ item?.description }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

It also allows you to reuse the notifications without subscribing again to the observable.

Comment: Actually I have it in that way. I simplified the example but I have just edit the post with the full example. The issue is ngAfterViewInit is just called the first time the directive is built. I do not know if exists a hook that it will be called when the interpolation will change the second time.